# Use same XSLT code multiple times in same file

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XSLT code like following

```
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="v:Values = 'true'">
        <xsl:text>A</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>B</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
...
    </xsl:choose>
```

I want to use this chunk of code many times in the same file. Can I put it in a template and call it when needed?

Comment: http://www.webmasterworld.com/xml/3295698.htm.  See about halfway down the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - It's called xsl:call-template .

Any template can be given a name. The name can be qualified by a namespace. For example...

```
<xsl:template match="some match condition" name="call-me">
  bla bla bla (template content)
</xsl:template>
```

If the template has a name, it you can even omit the match condition like so...

```
<xsl:template name="call-me">
 <xsl:param name="phone-number" />
  bla bla bla (template content)
</xsl:template>
```

Named templates have as many parameters as you like. The above fragment is an example of declaring one parameter named phone-number. Within the template's sequence constructor, you will refer to this parameter, in the same manner as a variable, like so...

```
$phone-number
```

To invoke a named-template, use xsl:call-template from within a sequence constructor. For example ...

```
<xsl:call-template name="call-me">
 <xsl:with-param name="phone-number" select="'55512345678'" />
</xsl:template>
```

Notice that `xsl:with-param` is used to pass actual parameter value.

Note that in XSLT 2.0 you can also define functions callable from within XPATH expressions. In some circumstances, functions may be a better alternative to named templates.

Refer:

1. [XSLT 2.0 spec re.: named templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-call-template).
2. [XSLT 1.0 spec re.: named templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#named-templates).

Comment: Is there a way to change the context node when calling a template? This is necessary since inside the template, I use only relative xpath.

Comment: Yes. xsl:apply-templates and xsl:for-each both change the context node. For more details in answer, provide more details in question.

Comment: I found a workaround to the problem. Thank you for your help.